# How to set spacing in Grid?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a grid of elements:

```
Grid {
    ForEach(viewModel.rows, id: \.id) { row in
        GridRow {
            ForEach(row.users, id: \.id) { user in
                UserCellView(user: user, size: (geometry.size.width - 40) / 4)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Given that I know that I have 4 elements in the grid, I just divide the size of the screen by 4 (which I get through a GeometryReader object).

The result is what you can see in the picture:

[image]

But I didn't find any way of setting the spacing myself. Like you can see the objects are not really well aligned, because the first element has a zero spacing from the leading of the view, and the last one has a too broad spacing.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you where looking for?:

```
import SwiftUI

    struct grid_test: View {
        var body: some View {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                ScrollView {
                    Grid {
                        ForEach(1...2, id: \.self) { row in
                            GridRow(alignment: .center) {
                                ForEach(1...4, id: \.self) { number in
                                    
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("\(number)")
                                    }
                                    
                                    .frame(width: ((geometry.size.width - 40) / 4), height: 80)
                                    .background(Color.red)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .border(.blue)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]